# asp.net Deleted Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

Warning 28  The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Google.Protobuf, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".    MMS

what's this error suppose to mean? plz help

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And it doesn't mean "deleted framework". And it means you're using a package that's for .NET v4.5 but you're targeting .NET 4.0. You might consider updating to 4.5 or later.

Comment: already done. But not working

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the current project properties, there is a target framework.  You need to change it to 4.5 or above